How to run pure Kafka and Kafka Connect over docker-compose?
I am writing my first Kafka based project and experience some issues with integration. Kafka and Kafka Connect. Here is my docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  database:
    image: 'postgres:16.2-alpine'
    restart: always
    shm_size: 128mb
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - ./database/.env
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.3
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - kafka-connect

  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      # - ./kafka/zookeeper/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka/zookeeper/data:/data  
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.5

  kafka:
    image: apache/kafka:3.7.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    volumes:
      # - ./kafka/connect-plugins:/opt/kafka/connect-plugins
      - ./kafka/config:/opt/kafka/custom-config
      - ./kafka/logs:/var/lib/kafka/data
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.2
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  
  # kafka-connect:
  #   image: apache/kafka:3.7.0
  #   command: bash -c "/opt/kafka/bin/connect-standalone.sh /opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties" 
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./kafka/connect-plugins:/opt/kafka/connect-plugins
  #     - ./kafka/connect-standalone.properties:/opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone.properties
  #     - ./kafka/connect-standalone-worker.properties:/opt/kafka/config/connect-standalone-worker.properties
  #   networks:
  #     priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
  #       ipv4_address: 172.16.254.4
  #   depends_on:
  #     - kafka

  # adminer:
  #   image: adminer
  #   restart: always
  #   ports:
  #     - 8080:8080
  #   networks:
  #     priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
  #       ipv4_address: 172.16.254.1

networks:
  priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.254.0/28  

Kafka connect is temporarily commented out to fix first issues Kafka Zookeeper vs KRaft conflict.
At this moment the Kafka service exits with issue:
The kafka configuration file appears to be for a legacy cluster. Formatting is only supported for clusters in KRaft mode.

Zookeeper is going to be removed in the next release of Apache Kafka, but in 3.7 release it is just marked deprecated. Zookeeper and KRaft are mutually exclusive mechanisms and should not work together, but neither I omit KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181 from KRaft configuration or omit configs related to KRaft I receive an exception.
ConfigException: Missing required configuration `zookeeper.connect` which has no default value.

or like another above.
General context is I want my Kafka data being mirrored into postgres. I already have working Kafka service queue where is producer put messages and consumers reads them and I want now to have this messages stored in PostgreSQL db in addition to Kafka queue. I have t write PostgreSQL sink connector and choose either Zookeeper or KRaft orchestrate mode. I avoid usage proprietary solutions like Confluent and keep as pure as it possible on the plain Kafka, althought fully open-sourced solutions are ok.
Could you help me please figure out with my current issue? Just for case of simplicity I am fine with Zookeeper and postpone with KRaft integration for future.

I haven't resolved this issue on docker based apache/kafka images, but I have solved my task by migrating on confluentinc/cn-kafka docker based images. Here is a final docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.2

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://172.16.254.3:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      # KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      # CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      # KAFKA_CONFLUENT_METADATA_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      # KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.3

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.2.0
    container_name: connect
    hostname: connect
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 172.16.254.4
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      # CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      # CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
      CONNECT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/postgresql-42.2.23.jar:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/kafka-connect-jdbc-10.7.6.jar
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-connect/connectors:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
      - ./kafka-connect/config:/etc/kafka-connect
      - ./kafka-connect/postgresql-42.2.23.jar:/usr/share/java/postgresql-42.2.23.jar
      # - ./kafka-connect/jdbc-driver/postgresql-42.2.23.jar:/usr/share/java/postgresql-42.2.3.jar
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.4

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:16.2-alpine'
    container_name: postgres 
    restart: always
    shm_size: 128mb
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - ./database/.env
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.254.5
    depends_on:
      - kafka

networks:
  priv-aeroflot-pilot-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.254.0/28  

Confluent shares this images under Apache 2.0 license which is ok for current goal, however I am still interested to find a solution on pure Apache Kafka.

It seems kafka is already ditching zookeeper in their docker image.
The Kafka docker image uses kraft config file: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.7.0/docker/jvm/Dockerfile#L81

Thanks, but it doesn't answer a question. Anyway, the task is put on the shelf and there is no much demand here.
